# Why is my parent process not waiting the second time? C/Unix

Tags: c, unix

So, what I am trying to do is create a child process, have it execute execl and run ls. Then after ls is done, create another child process and have it run a cat command on a file. The second wait(pid) does not seem to wait for the second child process to complete before finishing. here is my code and output

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
int pid;
printf("In parent process, creating child now...\n");
pid = fork();
if (pid==0){
 printf("Now in child process...\n");
 execl("/bin/ls","ls","-l",(char*)0);
}
wait(pid);
printf("ls child process complete\n");
printf("in parent process\n");
printf("Creating another child process\n");
pid=fork();
if(pid==0){
  execl("/bin/cat","cat","f1",(char*)0);
}
wait(pid);
return 0;

}
```

Here is my output

```
In parent process, creating child now...
Now in child process...
"Contents of ls"
ls child process complete
in parent process
creating another child process
[username@host ~]$ "Contents of file" *cursor*
```

the parent process seems to finish before the second child is complete. There is only 1 child existing at a time. The "Contents of file" are supposed to appear before the [username@host ~]$ prompt. I think i am misplacing a wait or wrong pid assignment or something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce your example. Your code seems to run fine after I add the appropriate headers.

Comment: Sometimes it actually prints correctly, most of the times it doesn't though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `wait()` is not a PID. It's a pointer to an `int` where the exit status will be stored. You're passing an integer where a pointer is needed, which means:

1. The program might crash or corrupt some unrelated memory location as soon as you call `wait`. Its behavior after that point is unpredictable.
2. You need to enable more compiler warnings and pay attention to them.

Comment: Oh you are right, I was supposed to use wait((int*)0). Thanks a lot, everything is fixed. BTW, i am using gcc compiler in unix, how do i enable these warnings?

Comment: For a start, run `gcc -Wall yourprog.c`

Answer (score 0):

Although the Cat process may have finished the disk cache may still be holding the results... Instead of waiting for cat to complete wait until the lock on the file is released.